# Codeigniter/Angular2 Session persistence

Tags: php, codeigniter, session, angular

so I am developing an API first application, Backend with codeigniter-restserver (https://github.com/chriskacerguis/codeigniter-restserver) and front end with Angular2.

I have finished the backend and tested all endpoints with Postman including image upload and delete endpoints, all work fine.

however in addition to authorization http header, some endpoints are guarded by user login session checks. in postman session persist so if I try to upload an image to an endpoint it check if there is anyone logged in, if not it return a status code indicating "not logged in", then I go to the login endpoint login and then return to the image upload endpoint then it works (on Postman).

however from my Angular2 client application even when I call the login endpoint, its still returns the user not loggen in status code. when I then call the image upload endpoint, like it kills the session immediately it recieve response from the REST server.

my question is, what do you think Postman do differently from my Angular2 client App (I am using Angular http and observables).

The Codeigniter restserver is on localhost:80 and Angular2 client App on localhost:4200 in dev mode.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if this is direct answer for your question, but i hope it will help you understand your problem and how to continuo with your project...

I would not depend on Codeigniter's session, since you are working on Single page application and the "rest server" should be stateless. 
This also means that you should not look for the sessions in Codeigniter...

Your client application should contain session data. So you should use [JsonWebToken (JWS)](https://jwt.io/), which can be stored in local storage or cookie on client. For each request you can also send this JWT token to server, where you decode it with some helper function (i'm using [JWT helper](https://github.com/rmcdaniel/angular-codeigniter-seed/blob/master/api/application/helpers/jwt_helper.php)) and if verification is true, then you make further actions, else return Not authorised or some response

Comment: It is not possible to create a small app with angular inside a codeigniter view?
There is many possibilities of this combo and the question still seems valid.

Comment: yeaa its possible and also you can use codeigniters session if you wan't.. I just think that restfull application should be statless and there for you should hold session on you client not on your server... What about if you decide that you will connect another client on this application?